# AngularJS, DOMContentLoaded and script loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) the application bootstrapping starts upon DOMContentLoaded event.
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) the DOMContentLoaded event doesn't mean that all external scripts has been loaded. So what if:

- I have different parts of my application in separate files
  (directives, controllers) and
- DOMContentLoaded event is fired before all of my scripts are loaded

Shouldn't that cause an error: undefined functions etc? If not then... do I miss something?

Comment: Use manual initialisation instead then you can ensure your externally loaded directives etc have registered with AngularJS before calling angular.bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread the document on MDN. Stylesheets are not loaded before DOMContentLoaded (except if you place them before your script tags) but the DOMContentLoaded will only be called when all your scripts are loaded.

**Sources**

- http://molily.de/weblog/domcontentloaded
- http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/